# Cannot use a scalar value as an array when first opening phpmyadmin from xamp

Tags: phpmyadmin

I've seen previously asked problems concerning with this title. but my case is little bit different. I am getting this error when I first try to open localhost/phpmyadmin. it lists bunch of errors saying "Cannot use a scalar value as an array".

here are the errors

```
Warning in .\libraries\classes\Plugins\AuthenticationPlugin.php#226
 Cannot use a scalar value as an array

Backtrace

.\libraries\classes\Plugins\AuthenticationPlugin.php#67: PhpMyAdmin\Plugins\AuthenticationPlugin->setSessionAccessTime()
.\libraries\classes\Plugins\AuthenticationPlugin.php#248: PhpMyAdmin\Plugins\AuthenticationPlugin->storeCredentials()
.\libraries\common.inc.php#349: PhpMyAdmin\Plugins\AuthenticationPlugin->authenticate()
.\index.php#26: require_once(.\libraries\common.inc.php)

Warning in .\libraries\classes\Relation.php#82
 Cannot use a scalar value as an array

Backtrace

.\libraries\classes\DatabaseInterface.php#1547: PhpMyAdmin\Relation->getRelationsParam()
.\libraries\classes\DatabaseInterface.php#2482: PhpMyAdmin\DatabaseInterface->postConnectControl()
.\libraries\common.inc.php#358: PhpMyAdmin\DatabaseInterface->connect(integer 257)
.\index.php#26: require_once(.\libraries\common.inc.php)
```

[image]
it is not only this. but it is too many such like errors are appearing till the end of the scroll. I am afraid of not to loose my databases. Can any one tell me what mistake do I made and how to solve it please?

Comment: I would suggest that maybe the install of XAMPP did not work or has somehow failed some of the parts

Comment: What version of XAMPP did you install? Is this windows or a *nix? What version of the OS?

Comment: my XAMPP is version 3.2.2 and and I have microsoft windows version 1809 OS

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[image]

I have tried hard reload but no luck but then i have done the task As Displayed in above image then phpmyAdmin is running as it should be.

So to do it first of all press `F12` on your browser to open developer tool.

And go to `Application` tab then on the Left side-bar go to `Clear Storage` as in **image redlined and numbered 1**

And now the chart will appear for storage data and at exactly below it there will be `Clear Site data` button as in **image redlined and numbered 2** Just Press that button and refresh the phpmyAdmin Tab it will definitely working now.

Comment: In my case: I inspect the page and went to the storage tab, cleared all cookies, and it worked fine.

Comment: @Imran_Developer Yes it also works sometime but clear site date clears all other data too, it clears Local and session storage, cookies, indexed DB, Cache etc, so it makes fresh load and prevent the errors.

Answer (score 7):

Use any other browser or clean browser's memory

Comment: Please add more description or improve your answer

Comment: I was facing the same with `PHPMyAdmin` on `localhost`, and clearing only `localhost` cookies of browser fixed this for me.

Answer (score 5):

I was facing the same with PHPMyAdmin on localhost, and clearing only localhost cookies of browser also fixed this for me.

Comment: What version of phpMyAdmin do you use ?

Answer (score 0):

Just press F12, You will see a top bar, Go to Application tab. After clicking on Application, click on storage which will be displayed on left bottom corner. When you'll click Storage a chart will open with a button CLEAR SITE DATA. Click on the button and your issue will be resolved.
Remember to be on the page/tab on whci