# Fatal error occurred in XAMPP server when running a sql command

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am trying develop a vehicle booking system in these days. The backend server I used for developing the system is, "XAMPP Server" Until today, the server works properly. But today, when I run a sql query it directed the server into a fatal error. The query that I run is mentioned below.

```
CREATE TABLE UserContact(
    userID INT,
    Contact INT,
    CONSTRAINT usercontact_pkey PRIMARY KEY (userID, Contact)
);
```

After running this query on XAMPP server for long time, it generates this error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in
> C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Plugins\AuthenticationPlugin.php:257
> Stack trace: #0
> C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Plugins\AuthenticationPlugin.php(85):
> PhpMyAdmin\Plugins\AuthenticationPlugin->setSessionAccessTime() #1
> C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Plugins\AuthenticationPlugin.php(279):
> PhpMyAdmin\Plugins\AuthenticationPlugin->storeCredentials() #2
> C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\common.inc.php(263):
> PhpMyAdmin\Plugins\AuthenticationPlugin->authenticate() #3
> C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\index.php(15):
> require_once('C:\xampp\phpMyA...') #4 {main} thrown in
> C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Plugins\AuthenticationPlugin.php
> on line 257

The screenshot of the error:

[image: The screenshot of the error is visible through this link.]

Comment: See if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55543497/cannot-use-a-scalar-value-as-an-array-when-first-opening-phpmyadmin-from-xamp helps

Comment: Try adding what you have tried so far, as the question stands now it seems as if you encountered the problem and instantly threw it here.

Comment: Check this post, this works for your case.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56537958/phpmyadmin-is-suddenly-showing-errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56537958/phpmyadmin-is-suddenly-showing-errors)